# How can I prove DP completeness?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete, np

We defined the class $\text{DP}$ like this:

$$\text{DP} := \{ A \setminus B : A, B \in \text{NP} \}$$

We say a problem $P$ is $\text{DP}$ complete iff $P \in \text{DP}$ and $X \leq P \forall X \in \text{DP}$, meaning that every language $X \in \text{DP}$ can be reduced to $P$ in polynomial time.

For a particular problem (which I do not expect you to solve, so I won't explain all the details), I already proved that $P \in \text{DP}$, but I do not know how to continue. Also, I could not find more information about this class.

Could someone give me a hint how to start such a proof or point me to further information about this complexity class which might help me to achieve it?

**Edit**: The definition is from a lecture about complexity of algorithms. The task is to prove that

$$\text{SAT-UNSAT} = \{\, (F,G) : F \text{ is satisfiable}, G \text{ is not}\, \}$$

is DP-complete. I proved that $\text{SAT-UNSAT} \in \text{DP}$, but I failed to prove the completeness.

Comment: What's the context in which you encountered this interesting question?  Can you share more where it came from?  Did you see this in a textbook?  in a complexity theory course?  Can you credit the source where it appeared?

Comment: What's the definition of $\leq$ here? Why is DP not the same as NP?

Comment: @D.W. I added some further details. As this is an internal document of the lecture, I don't think I can credit the source here.

Comment: @Raphael I added a note explaining it. $A \leq B$ (formally $A \leq_m^P B$) means that $A$ can be reduced to $B$ in polynomial time.

Comment: @Raphael Do you think DP is the same as NP? Maybe with an argument such as "simulate a NTM for A. If $x \notin A$, abort. Simulate a NTM for B. Accept iff $x \notin B$"?

Comment: You absolutely *have* to credit the source, if only by the name of the author.

Comment: @just.kidding That construction won't work (the running-times in the reject case are wrong). I don't know, but it strikes me as an interesting question. In particular, if DP = NP the task it a usual NP-completeness proof, which is a neat enough joke for it to have occurred to a teacher. ;D

Answer (score 4):

The DP-hardness of SAT-UNSAT is a direct consequence of the fact that SAT is NP-hard.

Suppose that $L \in \mathrm{DP}$. Then there exist languages $A \in \mathrm{NP}$ and $B \in \mathrm{coNP}$ such that $L = A \cap B$. Since SAT is NP-complete, there exists a polytime reduction $f$ such that $x \in A$ iff $f(x) \in \mathrm{SAT}$. Since UNSAT is coNP-complete, there exists a polytime reduction $g$ such that $x \in B$ iff $g(x) \in \mathrm{coSAT}$. You can check that the polytime reduction $h(x) = (f(x),g(x))$ satisfies $x \in L$ iff $h(x) \in \mathrm{SAT\text{-}UNSAT}$. This shows that SAT-UNSAT is DP-hard.

To complete the proof that SAT-UNSAT is DP-complete, you have to show that SAT-UNSAT is in DP. Presumably you already know how to do that.

Note that DP contains both SAT and UNSAT, and in particular differs from NP unless NP=coNP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But why isn't DP = NP? If a language is in $NP$, it must be in $DP$ as well ($L = L \setminus \varnothing$, and $L, \varnothing \in NP$). If a language $L = A \setminus B$ is in DP, we can simulate non-deterministic turing machines for $A$ and $B$ to decide $L$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: DP also contains coNP. Your argument would show that NP equals coNP, which is conjectured not to hold. I suggest reviewing the definition of non deterministic Turing machine.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you with this, but I cannot find a mistake in my attempt. Ahhhh are you referring to the fact that NTMs only complete in polynomial time for $x \in L$, but not in $x \notin L$? I never really managed to wrap my head around that.

Comment: I suggest dwelling on the difference between NP and coNP, and understanding why they are (probably) not the same. Take another look at their definitions.